# Updating Sharepoint list item

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I am trying to update list item using below mentioned code

```
var soapEnv="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> \
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'> \
    <soap12:Body> \
        <UpdateListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
            <listName>TestList</listName> \
                <updates> \
                    <Batch OnError='Continue'> \
                        <Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'> \
                            <Field Name='RoleAsignedToSkill'>"+align+"</Field> \
                            <Field Name='CrossCapability'>"+ccap+"</Field> \
                            <Field Name='CrossSpecialty'>"+cspcl+"</Field> \
                            <Field Name='CrossSkill'>"+cskill+"</Field> \
                            <Field Name='SuggestedTraining'>"+st+"</Field> \
                            <Field Name='ToCrossSkill'>"+tcs+"</Field> \
                            <Field Name='Status'>Done</Field> \
                            <Field Name='ID'>"+rid+"</Field> \
                        </Method> \
                    </Batch> \
                </updates> \
        </UpdateListItems> \
    </soap12:Body> \
</soap12:Envelope>";    

$.ajax({
url: "https://test.com/sites/test/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems");
},
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",
data: soapEnv,
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""  });
```

All columns in the list are of "Single line of text" with max character set at 255.
Now the problem is if I send data of 30 character length then the data is getting updated but not if its more than that. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Batch mode. but check this link : [Field Element in Batch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580(v=office.15).aspx)

The attribute **Type** is required. May be with type "Text" (corresponding to Single line of text)

like :

```
var soapEnv=" ....
              .....
             <Field Name='RoleAsignedToSkill' Type='Text'>"+align+"</Field> 
            .....
```